# Yii2/PHP date formatter seconds and locale

Tags: php, yii2

I use the following Yii2 PHP code to format my date object taking locale into account [Class yii\i18n\Formatter](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter):

```
$formatter->asDatetime($date, 'short');
```

It produces the following output:

```
14.07.18, 20:52 
7/14/18, 8:52 PM
```

I also interested in the seconds, to get something like:

```
14.07.18, 20:52:32 
7/14/18, 8:52:32 PM
```

How to achieve this with Yii2 or with pure PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `'short'` with `'dd.MM.yy, HH:mm:ss'` for the first format and with `'M/dd/yy, h:mm:ss a'` for the second format.

See [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter#asDatetime()-detail) for the documentation of `asDatetime()` and [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime) for all formatting options.